# How to get only the link of a Link type field

Tags: sharepoint-server

Tengo un campo que se genera en el Schema.xml de la lista de esta manera.

`<Field ID="xxxxx" Name="xxxxx" DisplayName="xxxx" Type="Link" RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="ThemeHtml" Required="TRUE" />`

Por código necesito saber como obtener el valor pero solo el enlace, ya que este valor no solo devuelve el enlace.

---

English:

I have a field that is generated in the Schema.xml list this way (see above)

Using code I want to retrieve *only* the link, as my current attempts are returning more than just the link.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is an English speaking site where questions (and answer) should be posted in English

Comment: is not permitted questions in spanish or other language?

Comment: No it is not, for the most part of the members to understand all questions here (and also so that the moderators can moderate all questions), all questions should be asked in English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this link you will find the solution,

msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue

Comment: in my case it was in this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.fields.linkfieldvalue(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue)

Example:

```
public static string ParserLinkField(SPListItem item)
{
    LinkFieldValue currentFieldValue = item["NombreItem"] as LinkFieldValue;
    if (currentFieldValue != null)
        return currentFieldValue.NavigateUrl;
    else
        return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.fields.linkfieldvalue(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue